# Aspose PDF - Change background color of paragraphs that spans over multiple pages

Tags: aspose.pdf

In ASPOSE PDF, version 11.0.0.0 we have a paragraph that countains a Textfragment that is really long (it spans over multiple pages).

How do we set the backound color of all the pages that contains that textfragment?

For example, if we do the following:

```
var page = doc.Pages.Add();
var ppp = new TextFragment("super long text here......");
page.Paragraphs.Add(ppp);
page.Background = Color.AliceBlue;
```

only the **first** page that contains the TextFragment will be Blue. How to make sure that all the pages that have that textfragment will be blue? (since the text will ultimately come from a database, we don't know its length).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per your [post in Aspose.Pdf forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/671619/change-background-color-of-paragraphs-that-spans-over-multiple-pages.aspx), it is a bug in Aspose.Pdf for .NET dll. We have logged a ticket PDFNEWNET-39748 for the rectification. Please follow Aspose.Pdf forum post for the updates.

My name is Tilal Ahmad and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.